# How can I drop SAS variables with the same string start that don't meet a variable name length criteria?

Tags: sas

I am wanting to drop columns where the column name starts with the same string but the name length is not a specified length. In the example below, I am particularly interested in flexible coding that would allow me to drop references of "Var2021" and "Var2122" without impacting the longer strings like "Var202101". Note that the contents of all the variables beginning with the Var string are numeric but these are not the only numeric variables in the dataset. I am working with a very wide dataset so I have included a dummy version of some column names below.

- ID
- Date
- VarAnnualValue
- Var2021
- Var202101
- Var202102
- Var202103
- Var202104
- Var202105
- Var202106
- Entry_reason
- Var2122
- Var202107
- Var202108
- Var202109
- Var202110
- Var202111
- Var202112

Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Proc SQL` dictionary table `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS` to select variables that are placed in a list of variable names meeting your criteria, and put in a macro variable.  Then use that list in a step that will drop the variables.

Example

```
proc sql noprint;
  select name into :varlist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = 'MYTABLENAME'
    and name like ... criteria for name selaction ...
  ;

data want;
  set work.mytablename;
  drop &varlist.;
run;
```